# Sympy error on calculating reduced echelon form of matrix

Tags: python, sympy, linear-algebra

I'm new to linear algebra and sympy. I'm trying to use the `.rref()` function of a sympy Matrix to get the reduced echelon form.
My goal is to take a stochastic matrix, subtract the identity matrix and find the reduced echelon form of the new matrix. When I do these operations, I do **not** get the correct answer for the reduced echelon form of the matrix. However, when I assign the desired matrix to a variable without doing any previous operations, then rref returns the correct result. See the image below. Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are using floats rather than Rational. You can use nsimplify to convert the floats to Rational:

```
In [14]: PP = Matrix([[.9, .7], [.1, .3]]).applyfunc(nsimplify)                                                                                               

In [15]: PP                                                                                                                                                   
Out[15]: 
⎡9/10  7/10⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎣1/10  3/10⎦

In [16]: II = Matrix([[1, 0], [0, 1]])                                                                                                                        

In [17]: DIF = PP - II                                                                                                                                        

In [18]: DIF                                                                                                                                                  
Out[18]: 
⎡-1/10  7/10 ⎤
⎢            ⎥
⎣1/10   -7/10⎦

In [19]: DIF.rref()                                                                                                                                           
Out[19]: 
⎛⎡1  -7⎤      ⎞
⎜⎢     ⎥, (0,)⎟
⎝⎣0  0 ⎦      ⎠
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!